# Tuple-like structured binding for an inner class of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, inner-classes, structured-bindings

I want to provide structured binding for an inner class of a class template. How can I specialise `std::tuple_size` for that inner class?

I can't use *structured binding to data member*, because the inner class may be a type incompatible with that feature. So I need to provide *tuple-like structured binding*.
To provide such a feature to the inner class I need to partially specialise `std::tuple_size` in `namespace std`. The problem is that I got a *non-deduced context* for the parameter `T` (of the outer class).

I know that I could put the inner class in the global namespace and thus solve every problem, but is there any way to get the same result keeping the class inner?

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
class Collection
{
    public:
        struct Element
        {
            int id;
            T actual_element;
        };

    //...
};


namespace std 
{
    template<typename T>
    struct tuple_size<typename Collection<T>::Element> // Error! Non-deduced context
        : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2> {};
}



//Collection iterators...

int main()
{
    Collection<int> collection;

    for (auto & [id, element] : collection) //what I'd like to achieve
        //do some stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to provide a binding for this case: `Element` is already decomposable as is:

```
struct Element { int i, j; };
auto [i, j] = Element{2, 3}; // ok
```

However, assuming `Element` is actually more complex and needs custom bindings, then yes - you will need to move it out. However, it doesn't *need* to be in a global namespace. It could be somewhere else:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T> struct Element { ... };
}

template<typename T>
class Collection
{
    public:
        using Element = detail::Element<T>;
        friend Element;
        // ...
};
```

And at that point, specializing the bindings is straightforward. There is no way around<sup>†</sup> that since, as you point out, specializing on `Collection<T>::Element` is a non-deduced context.

---

<sup>†</sup>Short of a new language feature that would let you opt-in to structured bindings within the class body itself. There was such a paper for this, [P1096](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1096r0.pdf), but it was rejected when presented. Which isn't to say a new proposal couldn't do better.

Answer (score 0):

I do not claim the below solution to be the most elegant (or elegant at all) solution for the problem. It, however, achieves to add structure binding support for the inner class `Element` of the template class `Collection` by using/exploiting a C++20 concept for this very specific purpose.

Given that the `get` member functions, can be declared as free functions as well, it is possible to use the below pattern for adding structure binding support for inner classes that cannot/may not be modified (e.g., legacy, 3th party). The concept should be tweaked accordingly.

**Try It Online**

- [Clang -std=c++20](https://godbolt.org/z/hd7vYv94z)
- [GCC -std=c++20](https://godbolt.org/z/v8aMMdhef)

**Code**:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <tuple>

struct Hack
{};

template< typename T >
concept CollectionElement = requires
{
   typename T::type;
   { T::hack } -> std::same_as< const Hack& >;
};

namespace std
{
  template< ::CollectionElement T >
  class tuple_size< T > : public integral_constant< size_t, 2 >
  {};

  template< ::CollectionElement T >
  struct tuple_element< 0u, T >
  {
      using type = int;
  };

  template< ::CollectionElement T >
  struct tuple_element< 1u, T >
  {
      using type = typename T::type;
  };
}

template<typename T>
class Collection
{
    public:

        struct Element
        {
            static constexpr Hack hack = {};
            using type = T;

            template< std::size_t I >
            std::tuple_element_t< I, Element >& get() &
            {
                if constexpr (I == 0u) return id;
                if constexpr (I == 1u) return actual_element;
            }

            template< std::size_t I >
            const std::tuple_element_t< I, Element >& get() const&
            {
                if constexpr (I == 0u) return id;
                if constexpr (I == 1u) return actual_element;
            }

            template< std::size_t I >
            std::tuple_element_t< I, Element >& get() &&
            {
                if constexpr (I == 0u) return id;
                if constexpr (I == 1u) return actual_element;
            }

            template< std::size_t I >
            const std::tuple_element_t< I, Element >& get() const&&
            {
                if constexpr (I == 0u) return id;
                if constexpr (I == 1u) return actual_element;
            }
            
            int id;
            T actual_element;
        };

    //...
};

int main()
{
    Collection< int >::Element test
    {
        .id = 3,
        .actual_element = 5
    };

    auto& [id, element] = test;
    id = 7;
    element = 9;
    
    return id + element; // returns 16
}
```

**General principle**:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <tuple>

template< typename T >
struct Outer
{
    using value_type = T;

    struct Inner
    {
        using value_type = typename Outer::value_type;

        int m_first  = {};
        int m_second = {};
    };
};

namespace std
{
  template< typename T >
  requires(std::same_as< T, typename ::Outer< typename T::value_type >::Inner >)
  class tuple_size< T > : public integral_constant< size_t, 2 >
  {};

  template< typename T >
  requires(std::same_as< T, typename ::Outer< typename T::value_type >::Inner >)
  struct tuple_element< 0u, T >
  {
      using type = int;
  };

  template< typename T >
  requires(std::same_as< T, typename ::Outer< typename T::value_type >::Inner >)
  struct tuple_element< 1u, T >
  {
      using type = int;
  };
}

template< std::size_t I, typename T >
requires(std::same_as< T, typename Outer< typename T::value_type >::Inner >)
[[nodiscard]]
inline std::tuple_element_t< I, T >& get(T& src)
{
    if constexpr (I == 0u)
    {
        return src.m_first;
    }
    if constexpr (I == 1u)
    {
        return src.m_second;
    }
}

template< std::size_t I, typename T >
requires(std::same_as< T, typename Outer< typename T::value_type >::Inner >)
[[nodiscard]]
inline const std::tuple_element_t< I, T >& get(const T& src)
{
    if constexpr (I == 0u)
    {
        return src.m_first;
    }
    if constexpr (I == 1u)
    {
        return src.m_second;
    }
}

template< std::size_t I, typename T >
requires(std::same_as< T, typename Outer< typename T::value_type >::Inner >)
[[nodiscard]]
inline std::tuple_element_t< I, T >&& get(T&& src)
{
    if constexpr (I == 0u)
    {
        return src.m_first;
    }
    if constexpr (I == 1u)
    {
        return src.m_second;
    }
}

template< std::size_t I, typename T >
requires(std::same_as< T, typename Outer< typename T::value_type >::Inner >)
[[nodiscard]]
inline const std::tuple_element_t< I, T >&& get(const T&& src)
{
    if constexpr (I == 0u)
    {
        return src.m_first;
    }
    if constexpr (I == 1u)
    {
        return src.m_second;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Outer< int >::Inner ref;
    auto& [f, s] = ref;
    f = 3; s = 5;
    
    return ref.m_first + ref.m_second;
}
```